# How many points do you get for each weapon type hit in Wipeout 2048 combat races?

Tags: wipeout-2048

In Wipeout 2048, different weapons do different amounts of damage and earn you different amounts of points. Is there a list of how much damage/how many points each weapon type deals/earns?

Answer (score 1):

Because the game is so new such charts don't seem to exsist yet, however there is a list of the weapons available in the game and thier damages in relation to eachother, "Heavy", "Light", "Mild", ect... This list can be found [here](http://www.wipeout-future.com/wipeout-2048-weapon.php). As for the points gained for each weapon used and precise damage inflicted you may have to wait it out for someone to make something up.